# Facebook Pixel / E-Commerce: Deduplication for Facebook pixel and Conversions API events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, conversions-api

As read here [here](https://en-gb.facebook.com/business/help/823677331451951) browser events that were sent through Facebook Pixel and Server Events that were sent over the Conversions API will be deduplicated, for example, if they have identical event and eventIDs. However, if the data in both events is different (for example if the browser event has sent the email address of the customer and the server event has not) you will apparently get less "Event Match Quality" score.

I want to know if - in that case - the *better* event is kept (in my example meaning the browser event that has the email address of the customer included) and the worse event (in my example the server event that was sent over the conversions api) will be discarded while doing the deduplication.

I would assume that the *better* event is being kept.
But then, how is the "Event Match Quality" important for running the facebook campaigns?

Answer (score 1):

> Once your event fulfills both conditions, we keep the first one and
> remove the following one. **If a server and browser event arrive at
> approximately the same time (within 5 minutes of each other), we
> favor the browser event**.

[Source](http://%20https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/deduplicate-pixel-and-server-events)